# Precision with multiplication in Python's Decimal module

Tags: python, precision

I was using Python's Decimal module to perform multiplication and division under the impression that it would be exact (a/b*b should return a). However, this is not the case.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 50

dec1 = Decimal("703")
dec2 = Decimal("3499")
dec3 = dec1/dec2

print(dec3*dec2)

if dec1==dec3*dec2:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

The output I got is

```
702.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
False
```

My question is is there any module or function to make this process more exact? I have code that require this relation (a/b*b ==a) to be true.

Answer (score 1):

The `Decimal` class is meant for representing decimal numbers with a fixed number of decimal places. This means that most fractions will not be represented exactly, since they have infinite decimal expansions; for example, 1/3 = 0.333333333... will be rounded to a finite number of decimal places as a `Decimal`.

If you need exact representations of [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) so that multiplication and division are true inverses, use the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

```py
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a = Fraction(703)
>>> b = Fraction(3499)
>>> c = a / b
>>> print(c)
703/3499
>>> print(c * b)
703
>>> a == c * b
True
>>> d = Fraction(1, 3)
>>> d * 3 == 1
True
```

Answer (score 1):

When using real numbers, it is always recommended to not use `==`. The division leads to a real number which has a fixed memory (varies on the language), thus the division is always rounded off. Thereby causing the multiplication to give an approximate answer.

Instead you can use,

```
def check_equals(a, b, threshold=1e-6):
    if abs(a-b)<threshold:
        return True
    return False
```

You can change the threshold to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using that decimal module for the integers. Per the documentation, the decimal module retains significant figures, including zeros: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html. You should avoid applying this decimal module to your integers and fractions.